# How to reuse docker format image storage from podman

Tags: docker, docker-image, podman

How can I reuse the docker format images I already have in /var/lib/docker with podman? I have multiple GBs worth of images that I will rather not download again. How can I get `podman images` command to look in /var/lib/docker instead of /var/lib/containers? Do I have to go through the docker daemon unix socket? Or can I directly pass a file URI?

Comment: I haven't tried but probably you can run `docker save <image> | podman load`. At least you don't need to download the images again. I'm pretty sure it's not possible to share the image storage.